# Laravel asset() not working on remote while adding image dynamicaly using jquery

Tags: laravel, image, dynamic, server, assets

i am trying to show the images dynamicaly on remote server. other images are showing with `asset()` but i am unable to add the asset() while adding  image dynamicaly

here is the code

```html
<img src="{{ asset("' + grandChildColor.adon_item_image + '") }}" alt="' + grandChildColor.adon_item_name + '" style="max-width: 100px;">
```

and on the server i get the path as follow

```js
src=" + grandChildColor.adon_item_image + '"
```

how can i solve this?

i was expecting to show the image using asset but i cant get the actual path on remote

Comment: You can't use js var in php

Comment: yeah i realized later solved now

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this `<img src="{{ assets(grandChildColor.adon_item_name) }}" alt="{{ grandChildColor.adon_item_name }}">`, without adding other quotes

Comment: I did but it is not giving the actual path. Thats how it was solved
storing the url in variable and concatinating it with the path inside src

            var baseUrl = "{{ url('/') }}";
           
                            '<label for="grandchild-color-' + key + '">' +
                            '<img src="' + baseUrl   + grandChildColor.adon_item_image + '" alt="' + grandChildColor.adon_item_name + '" style="max-width: 100px;">'+
                            '</label>' +

Answer (score 0):

Thats how it was solved storing the url in variable and concatinating it with the path inside src

var baseUrl = "{{ url('/') }}";

<label for="grandchild-color-' + key + '"' + '<img src="' + baseUrl + grandChildColor.adon_item_image + '" alt="' + grandChildColor.adon_item_name + '" style="max-width: 100px;"'+ '</label' +